# Using Counter Cache to restrict maximum number of relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to block my users from having more than 5 pages. My pages model looks like this:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
  has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true, :strip_non_ascii => true
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :case_sensitive => false
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

And I've added a column in the db which is incrementing and decrementing fine.

I just don't know what I should put in my controller now to thrown an error and stop them from adding too many.

Thanks again

-- Update --

This is what my user model now looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages, :dependent => :destroy, :before_add => :enforce_page_limit
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :email, :case_sensitive => false

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true, :strip_non_ascii => true

  private

    def enforce_page_limit
      if self.pages_count >= 1
        self.errors.add_to_base "Page limit reached, can't add another page"
        raise "User page limit reaching, preventing page from being added"
      end
    end  
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `:before_add` callback on the User side of the User-Pages relationship. Check out the **Association callbacks** section of this page: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

You'll want to write the callback to check to see if there already are 5 pages related to the user, and if there is, raise an exception to block the Page from being related to the User.

**UPDATE**

Here's an example of how you would set up the before_add callback.

In your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :pages, :before_add => :enforce_page_limit

  private

  def enforce_page_limit
    if self.pages.count >= 5
      self.errors.add_to_base "Page limit reached, can't add another page"
      raise "User page limit reaching, preventing page from being added"
    end
  end 

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get the concept but that's way out of my field of understanding. Am only a newbie! Do you happen to know of any tutorials I can look at - had a look through the link you sent but couldn't see anything clear enough for me. Thanks again

Comment: I updated the answer with some sample code, does that help at all?

Comment: That's great - thanks again. I was just trying my own solution without success. Have put your code in my user model but it doesn't seem to apply it. No errors show, I am able to create a new page, even though I have reduced the count to 1. I'll put the code in the first edit...

Comment: @ctcherry Hi, still can't get this to work. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: A less clean way to do it would be to put the logic to enforce the limit in the controller. It would be in your page#create action. Check the page count on the user, and if it is already 5, don't create the page.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Is the one in the model above for rails3? Might sound stupid but it's not throwing a single error, or getting applied...

Comment: Yes, if you look at the top of the page that references the callback: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html you will see it references version 3.0.7.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'll have a look. BTW shouldn't self.pages.count be something like @pages.counter_cache?

Comment: I think it uses it automatically, but you could reference it directly as well. Either way, that count code should work, it just would have to lookup the COUNT() of the records, instead of already having it.

Comment: really appreciate the assistance with this. It's driving me nuts, I'd like your first approach to work. However I don't think it's being called - I've even removed the code and left the before_add and no error's thrown. Looks like I need something other than before_add. Help!

Comment: If you want it in the model layer somewhere (as you should, its certainly cleaner) you could try doing a `before_create` block in the `Page` model, where you check the users page count, if the user relationship exists. So, you would just need to make sure your page model gets its user relationship set before it is saved so it can look into the user model, and check its page count before allowing itself to be created. Make sense?